# Including keypad library removes sound from my piezo element

Tags: library, piezo, keypad

I am using the keypad library to include keypad and input numbers. when a specific number is entered a sound must be made.
However when I input using the serial monitor , sound is working. But when I include keypad , it only inputs numbers but not sound.
Help please , how can I make both work?
Thanks.

`#include <Keypad.h>
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {12, 11, 10, 9}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {8,7,6,5}; //connect to the column pinouts`

Then I get the input from keypad and store as result

`char guess = 'n';
 char keypressed = keypad.getKey();
  if (keypressed != NO_KEY) {
    char guess = keypressed;`

in void loop, it get result(key from keypad) and must play it: Tried separate sketch it works. but with keypad only input is , not sound.

`Serial.print("You guessed:");
      Serial.println(guess);
      result = checkYourself(guess);
      Serial.println(result);
      playSound(result);`

check yourself takes in guess from keypad ,checks then returns as result.
play sound function works when tried in another sketch( sorry not posting too much code its very long)

Comment: it is difficult to determine the problem area without seeing your code ... please include minimal sketch that still exhibits the undesired behavior

Comment: I just posted it thanks.

Comment: which pin are you using for the buzzer?

Comment: using pin 9 ....

Comment: which pins does the keypad use?

Comment: 5,6,7,8,10,11,12 removed pin 9 because not using a row

Comment: how di you tell your code that it is not to use pin 9 for the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it , piezo dissent work in pin 9 but works when connected to pin 13.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the pin connected to piezo does NOT used by keypad